# Why does my detached loop eventually get killed?

Tags: bash

In order to connect my VPS back to my home computer I have this script running on my home computer:

```
{ while true ; do ssh -nNR 1234:localhost:22 root@12.34.56.78 ; sleep 300 ; done ; } & disown
```

It starts a reverse ssh tunnel. If the connection gets broken for whatever reason the connection is restarted after 5 minutes. This seemed to be working well at first, but then I noticed that the loop only keeps running for a few days at most.

Why does it stop or get killed?

Comment: What happens exactly after a few days? Can you see bash/ssh from `ps`? I'm asking because maybe it's just `ssh` that hangs (it happens sometimes)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini all I see is that the process is no longer running (can't find it using `ps` anymore)

Comment: Can you try changing the command to `ssh -nNR 1234:localhost:22 root@12.34.56.78 &>> /tmp/sshtunnel.log` and see if anything interesting is printed? If nothing shows up in `/tmp/sshtunnel.log`, you can also add the `-v` flag to print debugging messages.

Comment: Also, is there anything related in the `dmesg` output?

Answer (score 0):

check how many processes this ssh command have invoked by this loop, you might want to add the following option in your ssh command line:

```
-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
```

check autossh which is working much nicer. I am using autossh+Cygwin under my home PC and can connect between my office and home for days without any interruption.